# Blazor / Variables not updating after @onclick Task

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm really new to programming so I apologize if I use incorrect terminology. I am trying to utilize Riot's API in a Blazor app, but the variables I display on the page are not updating to the values they have after clicking a button that uses the API to set the values. It may be because of the way I am instantiating the object.

I am trying to get **summoner.Name** and **summoner.Level** to display the name and level, but instead they are empty on the page, even after clicking the button. I've added a watch to both items and have confirmed that they are returning the values in the code, but don't know why they aren't updating on the page. Is it because of the line Summoner summoner = new Summoner();? I've tried setting it to null but that results in an error.

Here is the code:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@page "/"
@inject HttpClient http;

<h1>API Calling</h1>

<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="@GetSummonerTask">Get Summoner</button>
<br>
<p>
    NAME: @summoner.Name
    <br>
    LEVEL: @summoner.Level
</p>


@code{

        Summoner summoner = new Summoner();

        private async Task GetSummonerTask()
        {
            SummonerInformation summonerInformation = new SummonerInformation();
            Summoner summoner = await summonerInformation.GetSummoner();
        }


        public class SummonerInformation
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            public async Task<Summoner> GetSummoner()
            {

                var summonerName = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/weeatrocks?api_key={I have my API key here but taking out for obvious reasons}"));
                var JSON = await summonerName.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Summoner summoner = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Summoner>(JSON);
                return summoner;

            }
        }


        public class Summoner
        {
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "summonerLevel")]
            public string Level { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any error messages javascript or otherwise

Comment: No error messages in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the return to a local variable with the same name as the class field.

```
private async Task GetSummonerTask()
{
    SummonerInformation summonerInformation = new SummonerInformation();
    summoner = await summonerInformation.GetSummoner(); 
   // await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I added that, but have a green squiggle underneath saying "CS4014: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call."

It doesn't seem to be working, would adding await somewhere help?

Comment: Have you placed a break point to check the contents of the sumoner variable?. await client.GetFromJsonAsync<Summoner>(... ) would be a better way to Deserialize but its unclear what your API is returning.

Comment: I have! It says the values are:

summoner: {ApiTest.Pages.Index.Summoner}

summoner.Name: "WeEatRocks"

summoner.Level: "65"

Comment: Summoner summoner = await summonerInformation.GetSummoner(); is the problem you have a local variable. This is not updating the class field. Ill update the solution

Comment: Yes! That was it!! I took out Summoner and have it just as you wrote and it works!! Thank you so much! Is the await InvokeAsync necessary? I have it commented out and it is working still.

Comment: No I made the assumption it was not on the UI thread.